# I lost all my data, but has a back up iso and a livecd. What now?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, iso

Exactly like the title. A while ago, I back up my system with pinguybuilder

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/

Its output is an iso file, which I also backup to a cloud account. Recently I lost my data, and would like to retrieve the back up...

But I don't know how. Complete newbie here. I know the ISO file can be use to make a liveUSB but it has no option to install. It definitely has my old data though.

So what do I do now? Do I just manually copy them into my hard drive?

Comment: ehm: easier... mount the ISO and use your current OS to copy your personal files. No need to write the ISO to make a live USB.

Comment: What was the exact backup created? Was it system backup with data?or just your data? What is the size of iso?...u can simply mount it to see whats inside...u can also directly extract it anywhere..if it has installer of os or something then u need brasero or something to burn it into dvd or make live usb.. simply ans :it depends

Comment: @sardapv it was a system back up with data, the size is 3.9 GB

Comment: @Natural Please don't add "Solved" to the title.

Answer (score 1):

Thank everyone, after a while of fiddling, I make a liveUSB out of the iso. Now the USB can not be used to install, it just has a live session, but all the data, configuration is all there, just like a real OS.

...So I was thinking rsync

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync

It work.

I move the virtual OS to my empty hard drive. But now, every time I boot up, it went straight into the GNU/GRUB instead, and I have to do this-

> insmod linux
>
> root=(hd0,1)
>
> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
>
> initrd /initrd.img
>
> boot

Everytime. Oh well. At least I got my system back.

Answer (score 0):

I use "K3b" to make a bootable DVD from an .iso file.
I believe you can install K3b via the Software Manager.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1)  **Startup disk creator** from Ubuntu's repositories works like a charm! 
[image: Startup disk creator]
  Once installed you just have to launch it and select the ISO images of your back-up system to mount it on your USB sticks.
  It is very simple to use, you will see.

2)  Other option, easy to do but you have to pay attention (you could erase a disk) is to use **dd** in command line. Something like

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/backup.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync
```

will work with nearly every kind of ISO. 
 As I pointed out; pay attention when you use the command dd and be sure to give the path to your USB device after **of=** (device will be erased so you might want to check the data on it and eventually make a copy before proceeding)